# Forced transformation doesn't work before persist

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I need a filter to be performed prior to persisting the dataframe. To enforce this I attempted a `count()` after the filter + persist. While the dataframe read(at `Step 2`) is persisted(skipped tasks) the corresponding filter (`filter #1`) is executed every time the loop in Step 4 is executed.

Am I wrong in assuming that

1. `filter #1` is executed before persist?
2. count will trigger execution of `read->filter->persist`.

I would like to force the filter to execute once before persist as it is a very costly process to loop through the filter list for each iteration of `Step 4`.

```
Step 1
val dataFrame2 = readData(sparkSession, paths)
.
.
.
Step 2
val dataFrame1 = readData(sparkSession, paths)
.filter(col("field1").isin(listOfRequiredVals: _*))//filter #1
.persist(StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK_SER_2)

dataFrame1.count()
.
.
.
.
Step 3
val dataFrame4  = dataFrame2.filter(col("field2") === lit(52)) filter #2
.join(broadcast(dataFrame3), Seq("field3", "field4"))
.persist(StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK_SER_2)

Step 4
while( i > x) {
     dataFrame4.join(dataFrame2, "fieldX").write.parquet("path")
     i += 1
}
```

**Update 1:**

1. Updated the explanation with references to the right filter #.
2. While changes due to filter #2 is persisted in `Step 3`, `filter #1` from `Step 2` fails to execute before persist.

Comment: where is filter #2 in your code ?

Comment: My bad, I intended to refer to `filter #1`. I have edited the snippet.

Comment: Your dataFrame1 is persisted on dataFrame1.count() which is an action. I don't see another action before...

Comment: How do you know that filter #1 is run every time? What does `.count()` show, the number of filtered or unfiltered records? Does not step 4 keep producing the same file over and over (you never alter dataFrame2 or dataFrame4) infinitely (you only increment `i`, and `i > x` always holds)? Could you please provide a more realistic snippet, with fewer details removed? These details may be crucial.

Comment: The filter #1 runs one considering the execution plan. And dataFrame4 persists the first time you invoke `write`. Otherwise, @9000 is correct about this part.

Comment: @eliasah I needed the filter to be applied before being persisted. To force this I had used the `count()`. 

@9000 `How do you know that filter #1 is run every time?`
Well I was looking at the stages that were spawned as part of `Step 4` and one of them was `filter #1` And I may have simplified my code more than my actual implementation. `Step 4` uses the value of `i` to filter `dataFrame4` prior to join inside the loop.

Comment: Please try writing an MVCE about your issue and test it

Comment: @eliasah yes the snippet does look convoluted. Let me fix it.

`The filter #1 runs one considering the execution plan` - And it did, when `count()` was executed.

`And dataFrame4 persists the first time you invoke write` - I was of the assumption that the join in `Step 4` must have triggered it's successful persist. Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried to `cache()` the dataframe you intend to persist?

Comment: @AlexSavitsky persist does the same thing but an action is required

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question here is in need of a MVCE however I believe I have figured out the problem. The call to `unpersist()` was placed after a `join` (which marks the end of the persisted dataframe), but before a lineage trigger - ex `write` on the `join` result. As a result the lineage involved reading the files all over again despite placing a count operation after persist (which obliviously got invalidated by unpersisting it before `write`.